# Unable to use GMP with NVCC

Tags: cuda, gmp, nvcc

When I try to compile the following code with `c++` on OS X 10.8, it works fine - no compile errors.

```
#include <gmpxx.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) { }
```

However, when I try to do the same with `nvcc`, I get a ton of errors:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc47/4.7.3/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.7.3/../../../../include/c++/4.7.3/limits(1405): error: identifier "__int128" is undefined
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc47/4.7.3/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.7.3/../../../../include/c++/4.7.3/limits(1421): error: function call is not allowed in a constant expression
...
```

How can I use GMP with NVCC/CUDA? To clarify, I don't intend to perform GMP calculations on the device, just the host.

Comment: Uh, your error is unrelated to GMP, it happens in the standard library...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a `.cpp` module that you compile with your host compiler, and
   include your GMP code there.
2. Create a separate `.cu` module that you compile with `nvcc`, and include
   your CUDA code there.
3. Link them together.

Comment: This was not exactly the solution I was hoping for, but it does solve the problem. To anybody else unfamiliar with manual linking, [this resource describes it well](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_C_libraries.html).